# Light up led lights with python

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi3

I'm trying to light up my dotstar led strip from adafruit, with the help of my piano and python!

I'm getting the information I need from the keyboard, which I then try to light up with python. Only problem is, it's a huge latency. If I press multiple keys at once, the information in gets too slow.

If I remove the code to light up my led, its doing fine, no latency at all.
Is there someway I can speed this up?

I'm fairly new to python, so any tips at all would be very helpful!

Here's my code so far:

```
import pygame.midi
import board
import adafruit_dotstar as dotstar
dots = dotstar.DotStar(board.MOSI, board.SCK, 120, brightness=1)

def print_devices():
    for n in range(pygame.midi.get_count()):
        print (n,pygame.midi.get_device_info(n))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pygame.midi.init()
    print_devices()



def number_to_note(number):
    notes = ['c', 'c#', 'd', 'd#', 'e', 'f', 'f#', 'g', 'g#', 'a', 'a#', 'b']
    return notes[number%12]

def number_to_note(number):
    notes = ['c', 'c#', 'd', 'd#', 'e', 'f', 'f#', 'g', 'g#', 'a', 'a#', 'b']
    return notes[number%12]

def readInput(input_device):
    while True:
        if input_device.poll():
            event = input_device.read(1)[0]
            data = event[0]
            timestamp = event[1]
            note_number = data[1]
            velocity = data[2]
            print (number_to_note(note_number), velocity)
            dots[0] = (100, 255, 100)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pygame.midi.init()
    my_input = pygame.midi.Input(3) 
    readInput(my_input
```

Comment: `def number_to_note(number):` twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try thread the led function

```
import threading
Import time
lock = threading.Lock()
def feedLED(dots,color):
    with lock:
        Start=time.time()
        dots[0] = color
        print('led', time.time()-Start)
```

Implement it in the `While` cycle

```
...
timestamp = event[1]
note_number = data[1]
velocity = data[2]
print (number_to_note(note_number), velocity)
color = (100, 255, 100)
threading.Thread(target = feedLED, args = (dots,color)).start()
...
```

However, I feel you have some wrong settings, because this operation should be pretty fast.

Comment: I see! Do you think that it might be the midi data that is being processed too slow?

Comment: I guess you can't really measure the midi input. You have to check for yourself. The led stuff you can measure by time function. I edited the answer, there is standard example how to time code, specifically led feeding

Comment: Let me know further observations

Comment: I implemented your code! When I run it, and press a key, I get these results:
d 64
d 42
led 0.211897611618042
led 0.24943900108337402
I turned the led function off, and the midi data was reading really fast, so it seems that it's the leds messing up the latency.

Comment: Do you have 120 leds?

Comment: Yeah, I've got the adafruits 120 led dotstar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188763/discussion-between-john-carlson-and-martin).